# форма nodejs+nodemailer не отправляет форму на почту

Tags: node.js

```
  Использую nodemailer для отправки на почту, ничего не приходит в ответ выдает ошибку 404. Ниже приведена структура каталогов   


  Структура 
  node_modules
  public
  views
     layouts
        main.handlebars
     feedback.handlebars
     home.handlebars


  main.handlebars

  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Web Приложение</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
     <img class="logo" src="" alt="">


        <nav class="menu">
           <ul class="menu__list">
               <li class="menu__item"><a href="/" class="menu__link">Главная</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item"><a href="/feedback/" class="menu__link">Обратная связь</a></li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
   </header>


    {{{body}}}
    </body>
  </html>



  home.handlebars

  <h1>Обратная связь</h1>
  <div class="container">
     <form method="post" name="feedback" id="feedback" action="">
       <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                <label for="">Ваше Имя:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                <label for="">E-mail:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                <label for="">Номер телефона:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" id="">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
                <label for="">Сообщение:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " value="Отправить">
            </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>



  package.json

  {
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node server.js"
  },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
 "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
 "express": "^4.15.3",
 "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
 "express-session": "^1.15.3",
 "formidable": "^1.1.1",
 "mailparser": "^2.0.5",
 "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
 "sendgrid": "^5.1.2",
 "xoauth2": "^1.2.0"
 }
}

server.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
   defaultLayout: 'main'
});
const urlencodedparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('home');
});

app.get('/feedback', function (req, res) {
  res.render('feedback')
});

app.post('/feedback', urlencodedparser, function (req, res) {
  var mailOpts, smtpTrans
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
    service: 'Yandex',
    host: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@yandex.ru',
        pass: 'mypass'
    }
});

mailOpts =  {
    from: req.query.username + ' &lt;' + req.query.email + '&gt;' + 
    req.query.phone + '&gt;',
    to: 'radik.machete@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Обратная связь',
    text: req.query.message
};

smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (err, res) {
     if (err) {
        console.log('Ошибка');
     } else {
        console.log('Почта отправлена');
      }
  });

})
app.use(function (req, res) {
   res.status(404);
   res.send('404');
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
   console.log('Приложение запущено на http://localhost:' + 
   app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать нужный путь в action:
`<form method="post" name="feedback" id="feedback" action="/feedback">`

Comment: у меня появляеттся ошибка  TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'